# Show duplicated data with HAVING COUNT in MYSQL and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, count, having-clause

I need to show count of similar data from rows in one table to make a report, I have already this script but can't make it works...I see that with HAVING COUNT I can show repeated data and counting form row but I can make it

```
<ul>
    <? 
        $select_product_dups = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_diagnosticon, diagnostico, diagnostico1, diagnostico2, diagnostico3 FROM DIAGNOSTICON GROUP BY diagnostico HAVING count(diagnostico)>1 AND diagnostico1 HAVING count(diagnostico1)>1 AND diagnostico2 HAVING count(diagnostico2)>1 AND diagnostico3 HAVING count(diagnostico3)>1");
        $select_product_dups->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select_product_dups->execute();
        while ($row = $select_product_dups->fetch()){
        echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id_diagnosticon"].'">';
        if (!empty($row["diagnostico"]))
        {
            echo $row["diagnostico"]; echo '<br><br>';
        }
        if (!empty($row["diagnostico1"]))
        {
            echo $row["diagnostico1"]; echo '<br><br>';
        }
        if (!empty($row["diagnostico2"]))
        {
            echo $row["diagnostico2"]; echo '<br><br>';
        }
        if (!empty($row["diagnostico3"]))
        {
            echo $row["diagnostico3"]; echo '<br><br>';
        }echo '</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I need show the data like this(and if can be possible show chart too will be perfect):

- soriasis      4
- acne         20
- carcinoma     2
- melanoma      5

the data(soriasis, acne...etc.) is data inserted by the doctor

Comment: no, we're not going to teach how to do a chart in php. that's far too broad.

Comment: add count(*) to select and print it  too

Comment: @MarcB I know that, I need to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Change you SQL to something like this:-

```
SELECT id_diagnosticon, diagnostico, COUNT(diagnostico1), COUNT(diagnostico2), COUNT(diagnostico3) 
FROM DIAGNOSTICON 
GROUP BY id_diagnosticon, diagnostico 
HAVING COUNT(diagnostico1)>1 AND COUNT(diagnostico2)>1 AND COUNT(diagnostico3)>1
```

But this is assuming which ones you need to count and which ones you want to group by

Comment: I have this error in pdo:    `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING count(diagnostico1)>1 AND diagnostico2 HAVING count(diagnostico2)>1 AND d' at line 1' in /home/.../reportes.php:238 Stack trace: #0 /home/.../reportes.php(238): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/.../reportes.php on line 238`  that line is this:   `$select_product_dups->execute();`

Comment: Strange, could have sworn I put AND there instead of commas. Fixed them now. Give it a try

Comment: well now not show me any data, look in fiddle: [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80944/1 ] but I do some modification in the code and now show me the list but I don't know how count it, look this fiddle: [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80944/4 ]

Comment: The reason your first SQL fiddle finds nothing is that no resulting records have counts greater than 1 (ie, the check in the HAVING clause). Further it is grouping by id_diagnosticon. This is the unique key I now see, so not really useful to group on. That is my fault for adding it, but it was something in the original SELECT (and being a non GROUP BY, non aggregate value it would likely be meaningless in the SELECT). Remove id_diagnosticon from the GROUP BY clause. Also choose suitable values for the HAVING clause checks

Comment: well I follow this answer [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743263/using-mysql-count-to-count-multiple-columns?rq=1 ] and now I do it with my script, look in fiddle: [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddaa/31 ]  thank you for all your help  Best Regards!